# New apps uploaded in App Distribution don't show up in Crashlytics

Tags: android

I uploaded the app to App Distribute, but the new version app doesn't show up in Crashlytics. 
Therefore when I installed the app from App Distribute to test, it caused a bug but didn't show up for crashlytics also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase crashcrashlytics then it will typically takes upto 4 hrs for that.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But now, still nothing happened.